# Heroku RQ (Redis Queue) Django Error: "Apps aren't loaded yet."

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis

I have a functional Django app that has many Google Text-To-Speech API calls and database reads/writes in my view. When testing locally it takes about 3 seconds to load a page, but when I deploy the app live to Heroku it takes about 15 seconds to load the webpage. So I am trying to reduce load time.

I came across this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq that suggests I should use background tasks by queueing jobs to workers using an RQ (Redis Queue) library. I followed their steps and included their `worker.py` file in the same directory as my `manage.py` file (not sure if that's the right place to put it). I wanted to test it out locally with a dummy function and view to see if it would run without errors.

```
# views.py
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn

def dummy(foo):
    return 2

def my_view(request):
    q = Queue(connection=conn)
    for i in range(10):
        dummy_foo = q.enqueue(dummy, "howdy")
    return render(request, 'dummy.html', {})
```

In separate terminals I run:

```
$ python worker.py
$ python manage.py runserver
```

But when loading the webpage I received many `"Apps aren't loaded yet."` error messages in the `python worker.py` terminal. I haven't tried to deploy to Heroku yet, but I'm wondering why I am I getting this error message locally?

Comment: do you have redis running locally?

Comment: I didn't (total Redis noob here). But I just tried running redis-server in a third separate terminal and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the code of `worker.py`, but I'd wager it does not properly initialize Django. Take a look at the contents of `manage.py` to see an example. So, if `worker.py` tries to instantiate (or even import) any models, views, etc, you'll get that kind of error. Django needs to resolve `settings.py` (among other things), then use that to look up database settings, resolve models/relationships, etc.

Simplest path is to use `django-rq`, a simple library that integrates RQ and Django to handle all this. Your `worker.py` essentially just becomes `python manage.py rqworker`.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never.
Django-rq requires Django2.0, unfortunately for our project there is no plan to upgrade to the latest version.
So if you are in the same situation, you can still use plain [RQ](http://python-rq.org), you just need to add the two following lines in **worker.py** (worker_django_1_11) :

```
import django
django.setup()
```

and pass the worker class like :

```
> DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=YOURPROJECT.settings rq worker --worker-class='worker_django_1_11.Worker'
```